# Matrix multiplication using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I was learning to implement dimensional arrays with the help of Pointers, stumbled upon a program - Multiplication of Matrices, but with pointers. I've understood the Matrix multiplication program without using pointers. It comes like this:

```
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
for(k=0; k<c1; ++k)
    mult[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```

Using **Pointers**, the code is like this:

```
for(i=0;i<r1;i++)    
for(j=0;j<c2;j++)    
for(k=0;k<c1;k++)    
    *(*(c+i)+j)+=*(*(a+i)+j)*(*(*(b+k)+j));
```

I don't get the above piece of code, what exactly are they **Dereferencing** and which *asterisk* represents Multiplication?

Sorry for my ignorance, Thanks in advance (:

Comment: The _fifth_ asterisk is multiplication

Comment: The seconve version does not work for a 2D array, aka "matrix".

Comment: The first version also uses pointers. You cannot access an array without them. Your question lacks information. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these matrices are two level arrays and consist of an array of pointers to arrays of values. This makes it *a bit* ugly to do it in the latter way.

First you need to find the pointer to the array you want. That's the first derefence `*(c+i)`. Then you add to this the item you want from that array and dereference again, so it becomes `*(*(c+i)+j)`. That's all it takes.

Now the only actual multiplication is the asterisk between the closing and opening braces:

```
 *(*(c+i)+j)+=*(*(a+i)+j)  *  (*(*(b+k)+j));
                           ^ this
```

If that code looks ugly to you, I can tell you something that will help: you can use the first type code with pointers too. `c[i]` is exactly the same as `*(c+i)`. So just use

```
c[i][j] += a[i][j] * b[k][j];
```

and your life will be at least 7.935% better, guaranteed.

Comment: So, in short. Instead of c[i][j], we use *(*(c+i)+j). And similarly for all matrices. Wow, breaking it down, made the code simpler. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AnirudhMurali Yes, and it will be a lot easier if you just keep using `c[i][j]` with pointers, since it looks a lot better and conveys the meaning that this is a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is for an assignment, so we've to implement it only with pointers. Got the concept behind this, will work more on this (: Thanks again.

Comment: **None** of the matrices is a 2D array! Although not shown, they should have been declared `int **a;` (or any other numeric type) according to how the elements are accessed. For a 2D array, the elements have to be accessed by `(a + j * COLS + i)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I use 3*3 matrices, and the code works fine. I don't understand the need for `(a + j * COLS + i)`, mind elaborating please?

Comment: @Olaf Bad choice of words. Editing.

Comment: I suspect OP already uses the first code with pointers. As a lot of programmers - including far too many seniors - he likely does not know how to declare and use multidimensional arrays in C. He just thinks (and likely leaned) the wrong assumption `int **` **is** a 2D array.